# Ubuntu 19.10 wallpaper issue

Tags: desktop-background, 19.10

I've been facing an issue when setting my desktop and lockscreen wallpaper. It works fine for a while but when I reboot my laptop it happens what's shown on the image attached.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar happened to me after rebooting. Apparently, the desktop wallpaper setting was changed to "fill with background color". To fix it:

- Right-click on an empty part of the desktop
- Click on Desktop preferences
- Set wallpaper mode to "Stretch to fill the entire screen"
- Click browse and select an image in: `/usr/share/lubuntu/wallpapers`
- The default is: `lubuntu-default-wallpaper.png`